# S-curve using linear potentiometer without huge power drain

Tags: potentiometer, non-linear

The following circuit uses a linear potentiometer and two resistors as a voltage divider to create a very steep non-linear S-curve as the potentiometer is adjusted.
However, the low resistances consume a large amount of current and dissipate quite a lot of power.

Is there a better alternative to this circuit?

[image: nonlinear potentiometer circuit schematic]

Comment: Another drawback of this circuit is, that the form of the ends of your curves is extremely inaccurate, due to the tolerances of the potentiometers which tend to increase at the ends of the track.

Comment: And another one: if the potentiometer contact is very close to either end-point a lot of current will flow through it. It might start smoking depending on the battery voltage.

Comment: Q: Do you need the S curve extending to the maximum battery voltage (i.e. do you need a rail-to-rail output) or is it only the shape of the curve you are interested in?

Comment: @FakeMoustache Very good point, this is something I will make sure to double-check.

Comment: @Ariser I am more interested in the shape of the curve because it allows greater adjustment precision to around 1/2 of the battery voltage.

Comment: Oh you want greater precision, I added 2 solutions to my answer. Just having fun with resistors ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, scale it down in current by a factor 100 and then use an opamp buffer to buffer the output voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffPbGA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will give you the same voltage but at less power consumption.

Oh, you want greater precision ? Then why not do that this way, see circuit 2 or 3
Of course adding the opamp is optional. None of these circuits will draw large currents
(if you don't load it too much) so are safe regarding smoking potmeters ;-)

BTW circuit 2 is the most commonly used solution as it is the easiest to calculate the range of the output voltage for (in this case 1/3 * Vbat to 2/3 * Vbat).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGLelB.png)</sup>

Comment: The only issue I have with your modification is that it requires a 1 Mohm potentiometer, which is not as common. But +1 for pointing out the reality of the obvious solution.

Comment: OK, then just use the highest value potmeter you can get your hands on and scale the 2 resistors accordingly :-)